# Race conditions in Cursors for Android?

Tags: android, cursor, race-condition

So I have this app that loads data via a provider into a cursor.
The cursor is then used to fetch the data for the app to use.
The loading process is done with the LoaderManager API.

Now the problem arises after I call `swapCursor()` from `onLoadFinished()` in some circumstances; the cursor reports having the correct amount of data, but when I try to access it I get a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The peculiar thing is, I know exactly which line this occurs on, so I put a breakpoint there that suspends all threads and tried to inspect the data to see what was up, suddenly the error disappears.

Now by trial and error I figured that the problem goes away even if I do nothing. Like literally nothing after it suspends everything. If I just wait for a few seconds before resuming execution the data is perfectly accessible.

So my question is: Does anybody know if the Android operating system does something in the background that creates a race condition? I don't really see how this can be a bug on my side since when I tested it I suspended all threads, so my app can't do anything while I wait for the issue to resolve.

As a sidenote, if I just replace the `swapCursor()` call with `changeCursor()` (doing this means I have to use `restartLoader()` instead of `initLoader()` due to some other feature of the system) the bug goes away, but I've read somewhere that this is not the proper way to do it, since it doesn't handle the closing of the cursor properly (I think this was the reason I had to use `restartLoader()`, but I can't really recall at the moment).

Some code excerpts:

```
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    ...
    getLoaderManager().initLoader( ACTIVE_TEAM_LOADER, null, this );
}

...

@Override
public void onLoadFinished( Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data ) {
    switch ( loader.getId() ) {
    case ACTIVE_TEAM_LOADER:
        activeTeamAdapter.swapCursor(
            new MergeCursor( new Cursor[]{ data, createNewCursor } ) );
...
}
```

And the offending line, called deep in the stack from a `CursorAdapter.bindView()`:

```
long value = data.getLong( data.getColumnIndex( getDBName() ) );
```

To me it looks like the data in the cursor is not properly loaded yet.

Comment: so what in the logcat? also, post your custom `CursorAdapter` code

Comment: The `CursorAdapter` code will not be of any use, because it is rather high level, with a custom ORM handling all the data code. The offending line posted above is an excerpt from the ORM code. All related code would also be several pages long, so it would not be feasible to read unless you were in the project. I will add the relevant logcat entries to the best of my abilities, but it is also rather long and filled with irrelevancies in between the relevant entries.

Comment: "To me it looks like the data in the cursor is not properly loaded yet." so `Log.d` its `getCount()`, you can also use `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor()`

Comment: weird, before calling  cursor.get* in TeamListFragment.java:274 Log.d the value of `Thread.currentThread()`

Comment: More wierdness; adding `Log.d( "DEBUG", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString( data ) );` before the offending line makes the bug go away. This is strange.

Comment: also for testing get rid of MergeCursor for a while: just use `activeTeamAdapter.swapCursor(data)` and see what happens

Comment: `Thread.currentTread().toString()` gives `Thread[main,5,main]`. Removing the  `MergeCursor` also makes the bug disappear.

Comment: `MergeCursor` is a culprit then, what is `createNewCursor` ?

Comment: try DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor on `data` , `createNewCursor` and the newly created `MergeCursor`

Comment: Interesting, I found the bug, kind of, but it still leaves a lot of questions. So the column I was trying to get was an int in `createNewCursor` and i was trying to fetch it as a long. Fixing it so that it is a long solved it. But this does not explain why I was able to fetch it as a long if i paused it and let it wait for a second. Maybe there is a casting process that happens asynchronously or something like that? And why did the version with an int instead of the long work with `changeCursor()` and not with `swapCursor()`? I would not think this is how it is intended to be.

Comment: i think you have a ticking time bomb inside your code ;-) and nobody knows when it explode... but with no code its hard to tell...

Comment: Might be, though this looked more like an inconsistency in Android to me, thanks anyways. =) I'll move this to chat by the way, since there was a lot of back and forth, and post a proper answer instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84910/discussion-between-andreas-hagen-and-pskink).

Comment: Previous solution was bogus, updated my answer with a more proper solution =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that `swapCursor()` does not close the previous `MergeCursor` cursor. Closing the previous cursor solved the problem, but introduced a new problem because you are not supposed to close cursors from `onLoadFinished()`, and when closing a `MergeCursor` the `MergeCursor` closes all sub-cursors as well.

This was solved by switching back to using `changeCursor()` whenever I use adapters to only display `MergeCursor`s (some of the adapters display `MergeCursor`s and `MatrixCursor`s when there is no data from `onLoadFinished()` and for some reason `MatrixCursor`s seems like they need to be closed between usages so this does not apply to them, I don't know why) and wrapping any cursors in a class that disregards closing.

`onLoadFinished()` excerpt:

```
Cursor[] cursors = new Cursor[] { new UnclosableCursor( data ), createNewCursor };
activeTeamAdapter.changeCursor( new MergeCursor( cursors ) );
```

The wrapper:

```
public class UnclosableCursor extends CursorWrapper {

    public UnclosableCursor( Cursor cursor ) {
        super( cursor );
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {}

}
```

A previous version of this answer alluded to the fact that this had to do with casting, but after more research this seems to only have been a symptom of the problem, not the actual problem.

Comment: hmm, strange, see: http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/CursorLoader.java#112 so it seems that `deliverResult` first calls `super()` [line 109] which in turn calls `onLoadCompleted` and then `close()`s the old `Cursor` [lines 112-113] so what's really the difference? Cursor is closed anyway

Comment: The difference is when the data has not been changed, and say an orientation change occurs, or other event that triggers a data re-send to your activity. Then the `LoaderManager` tries to deliver you a closed cursor, fails, shit rockets fan-wards, app crashes, etc, etc. This is why you are not supposed to close cursors form `onLoadFinished()`.